# disable html element in php after created it py javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am try to build a website with php in register form the user must be upload file one of this file may be exist or not if he/she select yes the file upload will be show if select no will not show but the file upload I have crated it by javascript my problem is when the user select no the php must not be see the file upload   how can I do that

the javascript code :

```
<!--Script for certificate language upload--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var $recurring_form = $("#apply_form");
        var $custom_other_amount = $recurring_form.find("#certificate_upload");
        $custom_other_amount.hide();
        $recurring_form.find("select[name='c_languge']").change(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.val() == 'Yes') {
                $custom_other_amount.show().append('<div class="form-group"><label>language Certificate Upload</label><input name="user_languge_image" id="user_languge_image" class="file" type="file"  multiple data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true"/></div>');
            }
            else {
                 $custom_other_amount.children( ".form-group" ).remove();
                 $custom_other_amount.hide();
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

The php code is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['apply'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
    $user_firstname = $_POST['user_firstname'];
    $user_lastname = $_POST['user_lastname'];
    $user_date = $_POST['user_date'];
    $user_gender = $_POST['user_gender'];
    $user_nationalty = $_POST['user_nationalty'];
    $user_location = $_POST['user_location'];
    $user_bulding = $_POST['user_bulding'];
    $user_city_code = $_POST['user_city_code'];
    $user_phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $user_cv = $_FILES['user_cv']['name'];
    $user_cv_tmp = $_FILES['user_cv']['tmp_name'];    
    $user_passport = $_FILES['user_passport']['name'];
    $user_passport_tmp = $_FILES['user_passport']['tmp_name'];    
    $user_diploma = $_POST['user_diploma'];
    $user_diploma_image = $_FILES['user_diploma_image']['name'];
    $user_diploma_image_tmp = $_FILES['user_diploma_image']['tmp_name'];   
    $user_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
    $user_image_tmp = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];   
    $user_practice = $_POST['user_practice'];
    $user_languge_level = $_POST['user_languge_level'];
    //$user_languge_image = $_FILES['user_languge_image']['name'];// HERE THE ERORR
    //$user_languge_image_tmp = $_FILES['user_languge_image']['tmp_name'];  
    // HERE THE ERORR  
    $academy_parts = $_POST['academy_parts']; 

    if(empty($user_cv && $user_passport && $user_diploma_image &&  $user_image)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                  <i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i> <strong>Oh snap!</strong> you Must upload your Docouments.
                  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              </div>";
    }        
    if(empty($user_passport)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
              <i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i> <strong>Oh snap!</strong> you Must upload your pass.
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              </div>";
    }
    if(empty($user_cv)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
              <i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i> <strong>Oh snap!</strong> you Must upload your cv.
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              </div>";
    } 
    if(empty($user_diploma_image)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
              <i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i> <strong>Oh snap!</strong> you Must upload your diploma_image.
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              </div>";
    }
    if(empty($user_image)){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
              <i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i> <strong>Oh snap!</strong> you Must upload your image.
              <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
              </div>";
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($user_cv_tmp, "images1/$user_cv" );
        move_uploaded_file($user_passport_tmp, "images1/$user_passport" ); 
        move_uploaded_file($user_diploma_image_tmp, "images1/$user_diploma_image" ); 
        //move_uploaded_file($user_languge_image_tmp, "images1/$user_languge_image" );
        move_uploaded_file($user_image_tmp, "images1/$user_image" );    

        $query = "INSERT INTO register(username, user_password, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_date, user_gender,  user_nationalty, user_location, user_bulding, user_city_code, user_phone, user_email, user_cv, user_passport, user_diploma, user_diploma_image, user_image, user_practice, user_languge_level, user_languge_image, academy_parts) ";

        $query .= "VALUES('{$username}','{$user_password}','{$user_firstname}','{$user_lastname}','{$user_date}','{$user_gender}','{$user_nationalty}','{$user_location}','{$user_bulding}','{$user_city_code}','{$user_phone}','{$user_email}','{$user_cv}','{$user_passport}','{$user_diploma}','{$user_diploma_image}','{$user_image}','{$user_practice}','{$user_languge_level}','NO','{$academy_parts}') "; 

        $insert_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        if(!$insert_query) {
            die("Insert failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        else {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                  <i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully Inserted <a href='#' class='alert-link'>a new post</a>.
                  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                  </div>";

        }     
    }
} 

?>
```

Please help me I am new in php world

Answer (score 0):

You could check in PHP if there is a file uploaded, otherwise you could remove the upload form using jquery's .remove() and .add()

Comment: can you plz show me how can I do that I have try many ways but it does not work:(

Answer (score 0):

Please give the details of the HTML also . Put the file upload under a div (say id = "uploadFile") and the option to select yes / no under another div . Now write an on('change') function in JavaScript which will take the value of "yes" or "no" depending on which you hide / display the "uploadFile" div .

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                        <label>certificate language <small>*</small></label>
                        <select name="c_languge" id="c_languge"  class="form-control required" required="">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        </select>
                        <div id="certificate_upload">
                        </div>
                        </div>

Comment: Now you want to enable the file upload if select option "Yes" and to disable the file upload if select option "No" , right ?

Comment: @exactly that what i need to do

Comment: Try this code:-

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#c_languge").on("change", function(){
                var ptype = document.getElementById("c_languge").value ;
                if(ptype == "Yes"){
                    document.getElementById("certificate_upload").style.display = "block" ;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("certificate_upload").style.display = "none" ;
                }
            });
        });


Please inform me if done .

Comment: Hello It dose not work the file upload did not show when select yes

Comment: Set the file upload div to hidden by default and set the values of c_language to "Yes" and "No" in the same format I'm writing . Also you can use if(ptype === "Yes") and give a try , it should work because it work here .